# UI Testing (casperjs) with good known status of data (mysql database)

Tags: mysql, json, bash, casperjs, ui-automation

I'm using [CasperJS](http://casperjs.org/) for automated UI tests. I've done the basic UI testing and validation with some random data, kind of POC. I've set up this automation using bash script which kicks to start the web server, load MySQL data from SQL file, start CasperJS test cases, stop the web server, check the log files.

Now, I want to start the testing with some good known status of data which are stored in MySQL. So that I can test the list data and form data with detailed field information with some known database status. How should I know the status of data in the database at a moment?

1) Should I use pre-populated JSON dumped file which has status and details about all data?

2) Should I use web service API? (web service APIs are being used to show/save/delete data from the web page)

Let's take an example. I've 5 users in `Users` table. Now when I open the home page it shows 5 users with some rough details. When I click on any record from the list of users, it shows a form with detailed information about that user. The webpage is requesting to the web application to get the detail about a user with the help of user_id to show the detailed user data in a form. Now I want to check that all the data in that form is populated correctly. So at the next step, what would be the preferred way, should I read content from JSON dumped file or should I use web service API (like webpage does).

Searching this problem online, I also found [MYSQL HTTP plugin](https://labs.mysql.com/). Should I consider this as well? and How safe it is to use? (I know from the docs that this plugin is not for the production, it is just for testing purpose only. :) )

Answer (score 0):

For the main question in cases like this I would change the database connection string to your `testing database` (this is a clone).

In your case use your bash script to change the connection string (file copy?) automatically before you run the tests. And when completed change back.

Your testing database is a direct clone of your dev/live databsae but with ONLY the test data you want.  Downside is you need to keep the schema in sync with DEV/LIVE.

Also another point to take into considertion is if your testing changes state (post). If so your testing data might be out of sync. One way is get around this is to drop foreign keys, truncate the data and load in a dump file.

HTH

Comment: Yes, I'm using the test database. I can do one thing, I can dump the data in json file of test db and before starting UI test, I can load that json dumped file into memory so the test cases can access the data when it needed for the verification.

Comment: and you're right when I post the data to server then my testing data might be out of sync, but at the moment I'm NOT worrying about that at the moment since APIs are giving the response with status success or fail!